# CakePHP 3.0 join on nested table with belongsTo

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, join, cakephp-3.0

#### Context:

I'm making a somewhat complicated nested join in CakePHP 3.0:

```
$query = $this->find()
    ->contain([
        'A',
        'A.B',
        'A.B.C',
        'A.B.C.D',
        'A.B.C.D.Z'
    ]);
```

The relationships between `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `Z` are as follows:

- `B` hasMany `A`
- `B` hasMany `C`
- `C` hasMany `B`
- `C` hasMany `D`
- `D` hasMany `C`
- `Z` hasMany `D`

Within the `contain()` array, I can do `A`, `A.B`, `A.B.C`, and `A.B.C.D`, but *not* `A.B.C.D.Z`. The error message given is:

```
D is not associated with Z (InvalidArgumentException)
Could this be caused by using AutoTables?
Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:
    • D
```

I have not found any misspelled references to `D` though.

---

#### Question:

How do I include `Z` in this join statement?

---

#### Code:

My `C` model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
class CTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('c');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->hasMany('D', [
            'className' => 'D',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => ['D.id' => 'C.d_id']
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('B', [
            'className' => 'B',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => ['B.id' => 'C.b_id']
        ]);
    }
}
```

My `D` model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table
use Cake\ORM\Table;
class DTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('z');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->hasMany('C', [
            'className' => 'C',
            'foreignKey' => 'd_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Z', [
            'className' => 'Z',
            'foreignKey' => 'z_id'
        ]);
   }
}
```

My `Z` model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
class ZTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('z');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->hasMany('D', [
            'className' => 'D',
            'foreignKey' => 'z_id'
        ]);
        // Unrelated to the join statement, but in here nevertheless
        $this->belongsTo('X', [
            'className' => 'X',
            'foreignKey' => 'x_id',
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

#### Database:

My `C` table columns:

```
id | b_id | d_id
```

My `D` table columns:

```
id | z_id | data
```

My `Z` table columns:

```
id | x_id | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your files need to be named `DTable.php` `CTable.php` and classes `class DTable extends Table` respectively.

Comment: Woops, that was my mistake. The class and file names are indeed `Dtable.php` and `class DTable` etc. I've edited my question to demonstrate this. I would like to add that that my trouble comes when trying to join `Z` and nothing more (it works with all my other joins).

Comment: Can it be a Case issue? `Dtable.php`VS `DTable.php`

Comment: Unlikely. The table names aren't _literally_ `A`, `B`, etc. The filenames are properly StudlyCased.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I can see, the problem is recursion betweem C and D through "hasMany" relationships.
Maybe renaming this relantionship in C as follows:

```
$this->hasMany('aliasForD', [
        'className' => 'D',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => ['aliasForD.id' => 'C.d_id']
]);
```